# I need use select sum that if

Tags: php, mysql

I need to use select sum that if I type in a textbox A: 28 find row A and add only the numbers that have 28

And if it is less than 28 go to the else if

My code, the truth I do not see the error at a glance only adds me everything

use the following but it adds me not specifically

```
if ('SELECT SUM($book_price) FROM books WHERE $book_name = $bookname' > '5000'){

    TextNode("Fallido", "Solo puedes comprar 5000!");

}
```

else if

Comment: Thank you for submitting a status report. Was there a question? I'm seeing what appears to be a couple of lines of php code that is comparing two string literals. I don't see anything here that causes a SQL statement to be executed against a MySQL database. (We will also point out that inside the single quoted string literal,  $book_price, $book_name are just characters that are part of the string, they are not interpreted as variable references; but that wasn't the question that was asked.) Was there a question?

Comment: Please post actual code, not pseudocode. What you have here will not work in any language.

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: I need if an example in a texbox $ bookname put 1, look for all the ones that are in the database that comes out $ book_name and add all the book_price that has 1 and then go to else if

Comment: Not is pseudocode, is php

Comment: This is not valid PHP. `'SELECT SUM($book_price) FROM books WHERE $book_name = $bookname'` will be treated as a string, not as a query, because you're not passing it through a database connection.

Comment: which one can I use, select count?